# Which is a better option for using OS on laptop: Linpus Linux or Linux?

Tags: linux, distribution-choice

I would like to know the difference between the two so I can install on my laptop from security point of view and as an overall performance.This is because I am being cyber bullied on internet.I have asked question on security and superuser regarding this.

Comment: How well do you know Linux?

Comment: Note that `Linux` refers to the kernel specifically, which is basically useless all by itself. As an end-user you would be more likely to install a Linux *distribution*, which combines the kernel, the base system and a lot of applications (such as an office suite, development tools, graphics editors, web browsers, etc. etc.) into a convenient package. A few examples of proper Linux distributions are Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL), Debian GNU/Linux, Slackware, Ubuntu, and others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linpus Linux is a Fedora-based distribution of Linux. A distribution is the Linux kernel plus bundled software that makes it generally useable (think file manager, command line interface, software installer etc.). Linpus was designed to be easy to use and is targeted specifically at the Asian market.

Linux is the kernel at the heart of all Linux distributions i.e. the software that sits between your software and your hardware, enabling the two to communicate.

If you're asking the question, chances are you're not yet at the level to work your way up from the kernel and few people even experts do that anyway. So, regardless of what may be wrong or right about Linpus, I would cross "Linux" off your list.

Linux distributions that are considered entry level and which may be of interest to you include Ubuntu, Linux Mint and Mageia and surely some others too.

Comment: Correct. Also, even if you are an expert user and could make your way up from the kernel (cool expression), in almost all cases, why would you do that? If you were an expert, I'd much rather have you do stuff that's beneficial to you, me, and everyone else, than have you fiddling indefinitely with your system.